# How can i print Java emoji on eclipse

Tags: java, emoji

```
i tried to use Answers which already were on stackOverflow but couldn't figure it out
```

here is my code ,
how can i print emojis on eclipse console
public class SipirtAnimal {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
          String name = kb.next().toLowerCase();
           System.out.println("================================================");
           System.out.println("YOUR SPIRIT ANIMALS ACCORDING TO YOUR NAME ARE ");
           for(int i=0; i<name.length(); i++) {
               switch(name.charAt(i)) {
               case 'a':{
                   String grinningFace = "\xF0\x9F\x98\x81";
                  System.out.print(b);
               }
           }
        
        
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
String s = "";  // Paste the emoji character into source code.
```

## Paste emoji character

Paste the emoji character into your source code.

### UTF-8

I suggest you set your project and [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) to use [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding  in your Java source files. This enables handling all 143,859 characters defined by Unicode 13 including [all the emoji](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html).

If using [*Apache Maven*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven), set a property `<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>`; or something similar in [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) or Ivy.

```java
String s = "";
System.out.println( s ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/0icjQZ).

> 

## `Character.toString( codePoint )`

Alternatively, pass the decimal number of the [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) for that character to [`Character.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(int)).

```java
String y = Character.toString( 128_512 );
System.out.println( y ) ;
```

> 